# How to select tables under replication in Postgres or List databases under replication in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication

I am having 3 Node Postgres cluster and want to know tables/databases which are under logical replication.
The issue I am facing is when the leader/master node goes down and one of the replicas takes over as leader/master node and then over time when the old leader/master rejoins the cluster. In this case, I want to know what has changed under logical replication from this new replica.

Note: New Replica would be synched and would contain the same data as other nodes. I am using postgres 11 and above

Answer (score 4):

**If you are using logical replication:**

On the **publisher** side, the `pg_publication_tables` table will show you the tables you are logically decoding.

On the **subscriber** side, you can monitor `pg_stat_subscription` to get the received_lsn and last_* time columns

**If you are using pglogical extension:**
On the publisher side, the `pglogical.node_interface` will show you the node id and its name. Also, the `pglogical.replication_set` table will show you what types of statements are getting replication in the set

On the subscriber side, `pglogical.show_subscription_status()` function will show you the subscription name and the status like `replicating`

Comment: select * from pg_publication_tables; returing empty. 

I have table reptable under testdb database which is under replication. Data is getting replicated, but no entry under 'pg_publication_tables'.                                   

postgres=# select * from pg_publication_tables;

 pubname | schemaname | tablename 
---------+------------+-----------

(0 rows)

postgres=# \c testdb 

You are now connected to database "testdb" as user "pgsudo".

testdb=# select * from pg_publication_tables;
 pubname | schemaname | tablename 
---------+------------+-----------
(0 rows)

Comment: how about `select * from pg_publication` ?

Comment: also, does `select * from pg_stat_subscription` show anything on that server?

Comment: postgres=# select * from pg_publication;
 pubname | pubowner | puballtables | pubinsert | pubupdate | pubdelete | pubtruncate 
---------+----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------
(0 rows)

Comment: select * from pg_stat_subscription --> NO

Comment: I am having entry under

testdb=# select * from pglogical.node;
  node_id   |       node_name        
------------+------------------------
 2849729983 | sub1
 3668605397 | pgnode-postgres-testdb
(2 rows) 


But I also want to know databases under replication, this entry I only gets when I connect to db which is currently under replication

Comment: oh ok, pglogical

Comment: on the publisher side, `select * from pglogical.replication_set;`   and also  `select * from pglogical.node_interface;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230927/discussion-between-dushyant-sapra-and-ewj00).

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Get the desired replication set ID (no condition lists all available):

   ```
   SELECT * FROM pglogical.replication_set
   WHERE set_name = 'your_replication_set_name';
   ```

   See column 'set_id' value (e.g.: 123456789).
2. List tables under desired replication set given by 'set_id':

   ```
   SELECT * FROM pglogical.replication_set_table
   WHERE set_id = 123456789;
   ```

   You will get all tables under the required replication set ID.